# VSCode C++ on Mac shows Intellisense code completions slowly and without documentation

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for C++ programming on Mac OS for the first time. I am very carefully going through the online tutorial [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

I am using:

- VSCode `1.59.1`
- clang `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`
- MacBook Air 2017 with Mac OS Sierra (10.12). Yes, I know it's old.

At one point in the tutorial, the authors talk about the IntelliSense code completion:

> Start typing `msg.` as you would when calling a member function. You should immediately see a completion list that shows all the member functions, and a window that shows the type information for the `msg` object.

They show this screenshot with function call documentation:

[image]

However, when I create the exact same code add try to retrieve the code completion, I encounter two problems:

1. The code completion pops up fairly slowly, at least a full second after I type `msg.`.
2. There is no documentation on the function call.

[image]

What is wrong? Do I just need a newer MacBook?

Comment: Could be the clang version isn't completely supported by the extension?

Comment: Have you found out the reason? I encountered the same issue.